# How to solve undefined method `deep_symbolize_keys' on rails6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I execute 'RAILS_ENV=production rails s' I got below

```
user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config': undefined method `deep_symbolize_keys' for #<String:0x00007f9fa98943> (NoMethodError)
```

I heard that `deep_symbolize_keys' is shown when yml indent is wrong But My all yml files are validated!

Any solution?

(test,development ware doing well)

Comment: do you have some configuration settings that are unique to prod, perhaps in `secrets.yml`?

Comment: Adding on to @dbugger's comment, you can see it's failing to read your secrets config: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/157920aead96865e3135f496c09ace607d5620dc/activesupport/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb#L33